Docker compose up issue
One of my tasks is containerizing an ASP.NET Core 8 application and configuring it to work with a single command "docker-compose up". I developed the application in ASP.NET Core 8 using C#. This is my first experience with Docker.
I have managed to set it up so that when I run the project from Visual Studio with Docker Compose (button), everything works fine. However, when I run docker-compose up in PowerShell, the application starts without errors, but I can't access it in the browser no matter which ports I try. I even added the ports to the Windows firewall, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
My github: https://github.com/baro0000/DockerTests
I tried changing ports, shutdown antivirus, firewall, restart and nothing helps.

Don't be lazy by posting a link to GitHub...post a sample of your code into the question so that we can see it.

Choose a better question title. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You didn't specify the pfx for https in docker-compose.override.yml. I see you have the docker-comose.debug.yml so maybe you have tried this doc  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-8.0#windows-using-linux-containers. If it works you could try with that default pfx first with similar configuration and explicit write the port mapping.
version: '3.4'

services:
  sotags:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8090
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8091
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    ports:
      - 8090：8090
      - 8091：8091

    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

